# Transform specif for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, list-comprehension

**Is there a way to transform the following (pseudo)code snipet into a python list comprehension?**

```
for img in imgs:
    for i in range(2):
       for j in range(2):
           final_img.append(correspondent_corner(img, i,j))
    final_img.append(center_crop(img))
```

The purpose of this code is to extract 4 crops correspondent to the 4 corners of a image and the center crop too. I could achieve the list comprehension version of this in case of the center isn't needed but could not figure out for this case.

Comment: What is the motivation for wanting a list comprehension here? I don't see anything wrong with your approach (without properly knowing the context). I think it will be too complicated in a single comprehension; readability counts.

Comment: Is `center_crop` independent from the `i` and `j` ?

Comment: @roganjosh I know that it could became extremelly non-readable code if done with comprehension. The main reason is curiosity.

Comment: @game0ver Yes, it's independent

Comment: In that case, you should probably be making some attempts on your side and asking for clarification when it doesn't work. The point of curiosity is to discover things about the language for yourself.

Comment: Does `center_crop()` take `img` as a parameter or anything?

Comment: Edited code for more clairity related to dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only builtin functions, list comprehensions, and list addition:

```
[item for sublist in [[correspondent_corner(img, i,j) for i in range(2) for j in range(2)] + [center_crop(img)] for img in range(5)] for item in sublist]
```

I did this by using nested list comprehensions to do the inner loops:

```
...[correspondent_corner(img, i,j) for i in range(2) for j in range(2)]...
```

then appending that result to a list consisting of only the center crop:

```
[[correspondent_corner(img, i,j) for i in range(2) for j in range(2)] + [center_crop(img)] for img in range(5)]
```

This gives a nested list of each image's results, which looks like `[[img0:00,img0:01,img0:10,img0:11,img0center],[img1:00...]]`.  It can be flattened with another nested comprehension of the type `[item for sublist in list for item in sublist]`, which looks like

```
[item for sublist in [[correspondent_corner(img, i,j) for i in range(2) for j in range(2)] + [center_crop(img)] for img in range(5)] for item in sublist]
```